# Compare Dates in SQL in Case

Tags: mysql, sql, date

For a task I need to update a table at 2 different cases once if the name is mobile business intelligence and if the date is beyond 1/1/2016. The first one is working fine but the second one isnt working.

Im using mysql on mariaDB with mysql workbench

```
update projekt
set budget = case projektname WHEN "Mobile Business Intelligence"
                Then budget * 1.08 
                else budget
                End
,budget = case beginndatum when < "2016-01-01"
    then budget *1.04
    else budget 
    End;
```

hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE ... END` syntax is [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html):

> ```
> CASE case_value
>     WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
>     [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
>     [ELSE statement_list]
> END CASE
> ```
>
> Or:
>
> ```
> CASE
>     WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
>     [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
>     [ELSE statement_list]
> END CASE
> ```

You obviously want to feed it with a `search_condition` rather than a `when_value`.

Comment: Oh, Thats what I was searching for ! 
Thanks!